# JSP Custom Tag :TagHandlerPool can not access a member of class Tag.QueryTag with modifiers "" Error?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jsp-tags

I`ve created a custom tag class QueryTag and created required tld file.
and specified in respective file using @taglib and tag is suggested by Eclipse IDE.
I implemented custom tag class by implementing Tag interface and declared it public.

but when i try to run i am getting following Error..

**javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Class org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool can not access a member of class Tag.QueryTag with modifiers ""**

I`m working with Eclipse IDE and Apache Tomcat 7.0.
Any solution to get around this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your tag has a non-public constructor, or some attribute for which the setter is not public.